# Remove CAB but preserve webview text selection

Tags: android, webview

I want to implement my own custom view (not inflating a menu item), I'm planning to use a toolbar to appear each time contextMenu starts, and hide it when finished.

the problem is: there are only answer showing HOW to clear/inflate another menu over the default actionMode menu

what i`ve tried so far:

-> [Use a custom contextual action bar for WebView text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection/22391169#22391169)

Overriding the callback at the WebView

```
  @Override
    public ActionMode startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback callback) {
        callback2 = new customCallBack();
        return super.startActionMode(callback2);
    }



 public class customCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    }
```

changing the return false to true, doesn't result in the desired behavior i.e. hide the cab

Overriding the `OnLongClick` is not a option too, since it disable the current selection.

Comment: I'm tying to figure out the same thing. I went through the same thought process as you. It's crazy that there is no simple way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer solves the problem: 
[android webview: prevent text selection actionMode actionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088057/android-webview-prevent-text-selection-actionmode-actionbar)

not the most elegant solution ever, but I just tested it in an app I'm building and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The Only way that worked for me (**only on on Android L+**) is clearing all the menu items from context actionbar from the activity

```
 @Override
public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
    if (mActionMode == null) {
        mActionMode = mode;
        Menu menu = mode.getMenu();
        // Remove the default menu items (select all, copy, paste, search)
        menu.clear();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "onActionModeStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onActionModeStarted(mode);

}

 @Override
    public void onActionModeFinished(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, "onActionModeFinished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onActionModeFinished(mode);
    }
```

inspired by  [Use a custom contextual action bar for WebView text selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336903/use-a-custom-contextual-action-bar-for-webview-text-selection/22391169#22391169)

Also I wasn't able to implement the custom menu usin popupWindow or dialogs or dialog fragments.

So simply put it with the webView in a frame layout and play with its visability and margin

Comment: This will not work, if you select more text(i.e scroll select text cursor) then all default menu appears again.